# Change image file name to unique using dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm trying to make an image upload website using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com).

I need to change the image to a unique name but I can only change the display name or the name that the image saves.

This the code that I got now:

```
Dropzone.options.fileupload = {
paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
maxFilesize: 10, // MB

init: function() {
    this.on('processingfile', function(file) {
        file.name = 'test.jpg';
    });
}
};
```

Comment: What code do you have so far/what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear way to do this.

[Uploading multiple files with the same file.name using dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589046/uploading-multiple-files-with-the-same-file-name-using-dropzone-js/26659429)

Use `processing` event: (**not working**)

```
myDropone.on('processing', function(file) {
  file.name = 'justin-bieber.jpg';
});
```

Comment: I not sure where to write it