# Change name of uploaded file on client

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following.

```
<form method="post" action="/send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filename" id="AttachFile">
</form>
```

I want to change the name of the file the user uploads.

If the user selects "Document.docx" I want to change it to "Bank - Document.docx".

I still want to read the file the user selected, not some other file, just use a different name for it when sending to the server.

I'm working within bounds of an application which doesn't allow control of the server side, so ideally I need to do this on the client. Furthermore I need this to work within the confines of a `form`.

I have tried variations of the following without success:

```
document.getElementById("AttachFile").name = "test.txt"
document.getElementById("AttachFile").files = "test.txt"
document.getElementById("AttachFile").value ="test.txt"
```

Comment: So you want to change "picOfMyCat.jpg" to "/banking/secretpasswords.dat"  before uploading? Good luck with that ;)

Comment: @mplungjan - I think the goal is to read the file the user identified, not some other file, just use a different name for it when sending to the server. So the file sent would still be `picOfMyCat.jpg`, it would just have the name `secretpasswords.dat`. :-)

Comment: @mplungjan, don't worry I'm trustworthy!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes that is my goal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know. I was joking. But the browser will not allow that usecase

Comment: @JamesWood - I'm fairly sure my answer is wrong, and see [man tou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51783076/157247) is right.

Comment: (The word "see" wasn't meant to be in that comment. *sigh*)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Your answer might be correct within the confines of a `form`. I've updated my question - sorry should have put it in before.

Comment: @JamesWood - Ah. Then I'm afraid it's right. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rename the file using a standard `form` submission. The `name` of the file being uploaded is read-only. To do this, you'd have to do it server-side. (The designers of file uploads seem to have either not considered this rename-on-upload use case or not felt it needed to be addressed by the API.)

However, you *can* prevent the default form submission and instead submit it programmatically via ajax, which *does* allow you to rename the file; see [man tou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51783076/157247).

Comment: Can a new file be created using js api, named and then filled with the content of user selected file.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it through the [`File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File). We can also use the [`Blob API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) to be [compatible with Microsoft edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9551546/#comment-3).

```
var file = document.getElementById("AttachFile").files[0];
var newFile = new File([file], "Bank - Document.docx", {
  type: file.type,
});
```

Here's a complete example — see comments:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="AttachFile">
<input type="button" id="BtnSend" value="Send">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("BtnSend").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Get the file the user picked
    var files = document.getElementById("AttachFile").files;
    if (!files.length) {
        return;
    }
    var file = files[0];
    // Create a new one with the data but a new name
    var newFile = new File([file], "Bank - Document.docx", {
      type: file.type,
    });
    // Build the FormData to send
    var data = new FormData();
    data.set("AttachFile", newFile);
    // Send it
    fetch("/some/url", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.text(); // or response.json() or whatever
    })
    .then(response => {
        // Do something with the response
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Do something with the error
    });
});
```

Comment: ...and then send that file via [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Excellent. I **knew** something was bothering me.

Comment: Does Edge support the fetch API ?

Comment: Do you think this would work within the confines of a `form`? I've updated my question - sorry should have put it in before.

Comment: @anjanesh - [Yes, since v14](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) (and `FormData` since v12). To support Edge v12 and v13 you could use `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot work on the server side then you have to either rename the file BEFORE upload or AFTER download. How you present the name for the user is you to decide.

Comment: But how would I do that?

Comment: I found this which can change the name before upload. https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/pull/955

Comment: Perhaps you can get a clear answer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589046/uploading-multiple-files-with-the-same-file-name-using-dropzone-js/26659429#26659429

Comment: That looks like its using a third party library that I'm not/can't use.

Comment: You can always download the libraries and use them locally.